# Crash when utilising a std:map

Tags: c++, sdl, stdmap

In my SDL program, I am using a map construct to simulate an "infinite" array of objects within a certain class. The code manages to compile fine, but when I run the program, as soon as one of the functions using the maps is trigger, the program crashes, returning a value of 3.

So, here's exactly what I'm doing:

```
class MyClass
{
     public:
           int MyFunction();
     protected:
           std::map< int, MyObject > MyMap;
}

int MyClass::MyFunction()
{
     ...
     int i;

     if( MyMap.empty() )
     {
          i = 1;
     }
     else
     {
         i = MyMap.size() + 1;
     }

     MyMap[ i ] = PreviouslyDefinedObject;

     return i;

}
```

When MyFunction() is called from a MyClass object, the crash occurs. It seems to happen whenever anything of use is done with MyMap: it crashes if you comment out the penultimate line and just try to return i, and it crashes if you just set i = 1 and then assign an object to MyMap[i]

This is the first time I've ever used a map, so I'm not certain I'm using them right. Is this a basic mistake somewhere? Can anyone point me in the right direction? Cheers.

Comment: No need for your if clause--the else statement should work just fine even for empty maps.

Comment: Everything you've included looks okay--can you elaborate on the declaration/definition of PreviouslyDefinedObject and MyObject?

Comment: MyObject is a struct with four variables: two integers, a std::string and an SDL_Surface*. Its defined in a separate header file. Its being used to store a .BMP file, its height, its width and its filename.

PreviouslyDefinedObject is produced by taking a filename (the input parameter of this function), loading a .BMP, finding its height and width and assigning each to the appropriate variable in the struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are calling the function from an uninitialized pointer, like this:

```
MyClass *obj;
obj->MyFunction();
```

Comment: ...Oops.

This is of course exactly what I am doing; forgot a line of code earlier on and haven't initialized obj. Having done that the code works fine. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Maps are used to associate a key with a value. If you're looking for an array, you should use a [`vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/). It will do a better job of simulating an "infinite array" than a map, because a map isn't an array.

Note you can allocate *a lot* of elements with a vector, usually. If you're really trying to simulate a large array, I'd recommend wrapping up a vector of vectors. With some math, you could create an `operator[]` for it that indexes into the correct array, to the correct element.

As for your code, there really isn't enough information to determine why it should be crashing, you'd have to try to create a minimal program for us to compile or look at.